# How to automatically load this javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

Here is my code.

`<a href="javascript:showPopup()">Click here<a>` 
I was wondering if it would be possible for it to be loaded automatically instead of clicking on the link? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `onload`(click on the target element or call that function).

```
<body onload="javascript:showPopup()">

...

</body>
```